# Normalise all elements in deep nested list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I have image data in the form of a deep nested list of ints:

```
len(train_data_imgs) = 3889       # number of images in set
len(train_data_imgs[0]) = 100     # height
len(train_data_imgs[0][0]) = 100  # width
len(train_data_imgs[0][0][0]) = 3 # these are ints - RGB pixel values
```

How can I iterate through these to normalise them between 0 and 1? Simply would require every number to be divided by 255.

Comment: What's wrong with dividing every value by 255?

Comment: You have 116.670.000 values, just the iteration alone will take about 10 seconds. Are your images in a format that allows bulk operations, such as `numpy` types?

Answer (score 1):

Use `NumPy` package to do in a line:

```
# Assuming an image stored in a nested list | here NumPy array
lst = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
lst

array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])

lst = lst/255 # That's what you should look for
lst

array([[[0.        , 0.00392157, 0.00784314],
        [0.01176471, 0.01568627, 0.01960784],
        [0.02352941, 0.02745098, 0.03137255]],

       [[0.03529412, 0.03921569, 0.04313725],
        [0.04705882, 0.05098039, 0.05490196],
        [0.05882353, 0.0627451 , 0.06666667]],

       [[0.07058824, 0.0745098 , 0.07843137],
        [0.08235294, 0.08627451, 0.09019608],
        [0.09411765, 0.09803922, 0.10196078]]])
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using numpy in this case?

Comment: The same advantage which `NumPy` can have over normal python `list` ;) Actually you can go ahead with normal list too. But what's the problem in knowing something better, especially when it's images. :)

Comment: The question then is how to get the images into numpy format in the first place, and whether they must be extracted later on again.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi True

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a better tool! However, if you already have an image in memory stored as lists of lists, why would it be better to convert to a numpy array and then use numpy vs just iterating over the lists?